# What to put in txt file when training tesseract

Tags: tesseract

I am trying to train tesseract to recognize a new font and was wondering how many words I would need to put into the txt file to increase its accuracy. For example, fo I put in just a couple of words but with different combinations or up to 10,000+ words?

Answer (score 0):

See [Prepare a text file](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract-3.03%E2%80%933.05#prepare-a-text-file) section of Training Tesseract 3.03–3.05 page.